# SDL "dropping" initial event?

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl

I'm programming things with SDL 1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. SDL appears to "drop" the first event given to the event loop. For example, if I were to check for quitting the game via the "x" box, and I click said "x" box in my application, nothing happens. However upon a second click the game quits. My game loop:

```
void game_run()
{
    int RUNNING = 1;

    while(RUNNING == 1)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&scr.event))
        {
            switch(scr.event.type)
            {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                RUNNING = 0;
                break;

                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(scr.event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    RUNNING = 0;
                    break;

                    default:
                    break;
                }
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        }

        // draw here

        SDL_Flip(scr.buffer);
    }
}
```

If any more information is needed, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your

```
case SDL_QUIT:
RUNNING = 0;
break;
```

to

```
case SDL_QUIT:
exit( 0 ) ;
break;
```

The program should exit immediately, confirming that the event loop works fine and problem is somewhere in your code you haven't shown. My guess is `game_run()` is called again somewhere, and because `int RUNNING = 1;` is set at the beginning of every `game_run()`, your enter another `while(RUNNING == 1)` loop.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you so much! :D